# php mail attachment fails in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, attachment, php

I'm using wordpress to create my site. Can someone help me figure out why php mail attachment fails to attach files from other locations other than my wordpress folder???
Here is my code :

```
$subject="Enquiry";
$to = "veena@phenomtec.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$url=$_POST['resume']; 
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($url)));
$filename = basename($url);
$parts=explode("?",$filename);
$filename = $parts[0]; 

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";
    $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
    --_1_$boundary
     Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

    --_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";


if ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){

    echo "<script>alert('Your email message successfully sent.')</script>";
}
else{

 echo "<script>alert('Sorry, message delivery failed. Contact webmaster for more info.')</script>";
 }
```

I'm able to attach files from my wordpress folder. But i'm unable to attach files from other locations. Someone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but make sure that `$url` is an absolute, rather than relative, URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then try this code:

```
$subject="Enquiry";
$to = "veena@phenomtec.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])));
    $filename = $_FILES['resume']['name'];

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";
$message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";


if ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){

    echo "<script>alert('Your email message successfully sent.')</script>";
}
else{

 echo "<script>alert('Sorry, message delivery failed. Contact webmaster for more info.')</script>";
 }
```

Hope this will work :)